# When will Juno send us some pictures from it's tight orbit?

Tags: communication, jupiter, juno

Juno probe has sent few pictures as it approached Jupiter from afar, but Jupiter looks as large as Moon on our sky on those photos. After that it went into (intentional) silence while it was trying to get to orbit.

Will Juno send any pictures from it's orbit? When, if the answer is yes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2016/06090600-what-to-expect-from-junocam.html

The first major day for pictures should be August 27th, but image release shouldn't start occurring until September/October.

Other dates of note:

Flyby 1: August 27th

Flyby 2: October 20th- No pictures planned

Flyby 3: November 2nd

Flyby 4: November 16th- The public can participate in online voting to decide what the camera will target

And then pictures should be taken every 14 days until the camera or Juno dies.

Comment: Usually pictures are released as soon as they are available in the beginning of the mission when the public interest is at its highest. It's good PR, it's good politics and it's the right thing to do - these missions are financed with public money and the public should see the results. I would expect first pictures to become available on the 27th or soon after.

Answer (score 3):

[The first JunoCam picture from orbit was taken on July 10, 2016](http://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/nasa-s-juno-spacecraft-sends-first-in-orbit-view) and published on July 12.

[image: Jupiter as seen from JunoCam]