# How is JunoCam different from a normal CCD camera?

Tags: jupiter, flyby, juno, camera

JunoCam has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/NASAJuno/status/753001106498850816) us! More background [from the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-36780756).

[image]

It is supposed to have several features that help allow it to work in the high radiation and magnetic fields it will experience during each flyby. Although it has a [4:3 sensor](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/KAI-2020-D.PDF), according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JunoCam#Specifications) it has a very long, narrow 18 x 3.4 degree FOV, and that there are three color filters, not the normal [Bayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) arrangement.

How does this thing work? Why such a strange aspect ratio? Inquiring minds want to know!

Comment: The wikipedia article is wrong about the field of view. The camera itself has a 58 degree field of view, but thanks to the pushframe imaging being used, the field of view is effectively 58x360. A much better source: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-014-0079-x .

Comment: @DavidHammen Excellent article! I like the part in the abstract where it says "...*the public will weigh in on which images to acquire*..." :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JunoCam used different technologies than does the typical framing camera one buys at a store. A typical digital color camera uses a Bayer filter pattern, a row of alternating tiny blue and green filters, followed by a row of alternating tiny green and red filters, each filter covering a pixel, followed by a row of alternating tiny blue and green filters, and so on. JunoCam instead has four filter strips, each of which is 1600 pixels wide. Three are in the visible range, the standard red, green, and blue filters based on how the human eye works. The fourth is in the near infrared and is designed to see methane. Each of the three visible filter strips are about 150 pixels high; the methane filter strip is a somewhat larger than one of the visible filter strips.

JunoCam uses two other concepts that you don't see in the typical digital camera. One is time delay and integration. The lighting level at Jupiter is about 1/27th of the lighting level at Earth's orbit (Jupiter orbits at about 5.2 AU). Juno rotates at 2 RPM. A short duration exposure would result in too much noise due to the low lighting. A low duration exposure would be too blurry thanks to that rotation. Time delay and integration means taking a series of short duration exposures and integrating them together by shifting the subsequent images to account for rotation.

The other key technique is that JunoCam is a pushframe imager as opposed to a framing imager. A frame results when the time delay and integration is complete (the number of TDI steps is commandable). This frame is pushed onto local memory. JunoCam alternates between visible and methane channel, so that means that another visible frame will be produced a minute later thanks to JunoCam's 2 RPM rotation rate. The result is a jumble of partially overlapping framelets that need extensive ground processing to make sense of the imagery.

JunoCam was designed to yield optimal performance at one hour before and one hour after closest approach. This should give good performance at closest approach, but more importantly should also give good performance over Jupiter's polar regions. JunoCam won't perform so well Juno is far from Jupiter (which is most of its orbit).

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the nice write-up. I had no idea about the NIR filter!

Comment: Is there any chance you'd consider adding the link to the JunoCam article here also? Then you could cite [Figure 12](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CPmSM.jpg) and also [Figure 13](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUrL.gif) and add include them in the answer. It's an "aha" kind of thing. Definitely not the RGB filters used to simulate human color vision!

Comment: Nice to see someone well-informed about JunoCam! I've invested some time to help correcting the obsolete Wikipedia paragraph in the German Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_(Raumsonde)#JunoCam). But the English Wikipedia version about JunoCam (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JunoCam#Specifications) is still based on an obsolete 2005 technical document. Since Wikipedia is used frequently as a reference, maybe it would be useful to be corrected by a native English/American expert. I've seen the same confusion as in the question several times in forums.

Comment: ... Btw.: Although the color filters are about 150 pixels high (plus a gap of about 5 pixels), the readout for the framelets is only 128 pixels high, such that for small TDI you don't get a mix of two colors.

Comment: @Gerald if nobody else picks up on it, I'll may make an attempt. I noticed [Figure 15](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vMfCK.jpg) of [the paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-014-0079-x) linked in [comment above](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17180/#comment44078_17180) is also relevant to the uniqueness of JunoCam's design for the Jupiter environment. What would be the procedure to contact the authors to enquire if these images can be sourced from a suitably licensed JPL or NASA site so that they could be included in Wikipedia? That process can be daunting to a beginner!

Comment: @uhoh -- That's trivial. Those images are copyright of the US government and will be posted on a nasa.gov page. They will be as "open source" as open source can be.

Comment: They won't even be copyright. They'll be public domain.

Comment: @DavidHammen I understand the basic idea, but I don't see *these particular images* on any NASA or JPL site. I only see them in a copyrighted article written by mostly non-NASA-affiliated authors. Have you found them in a NASA database, or are you just guessing?

Comment: @uhoh: Thanks for taking this part. I'd think, that Figure 15 is copyrighted by MSSS. The paper as a whole is copyrighted by the authors of the paper. Candice Hansen is JunoCam PI, Glenn Orton (JPL) is usually contact for Earth-bound observations. It's probably best to contact the lead author, i.e. Candice Hansen, with a short request for allowance using the image in Wikipedia: http://www.psi.edu/about/staffpage/cjhansen  She'll then forward the request to MSSS, if necessary.

Comment: @uhoh -- I'm very leery of placing images in my answers, for several reasons. (1) The imagery is typically copyright. I develop intellectual property, so I try hard to respect the IP rights of others. (2) Link rot. (3) I would feel compelled to add sufficient alt text to describe the content for the visually impaired, and that takes a lot of time.

Comment: @uhoh -- Regarding my previous comment, I thought you were asking about the images that will be captured by JunoCam once its up and running. Those images will be public domain. The images in the referenced article are not public domain.

Comment: @David Hammen. The raw JunoCam images will be public domain. But the raw images are likely to get processed by several persons and institutions. The license depends on them; it may differ between images. I'm intending to make my processed JunoCam images public domain, with credits recommended.

Comment: @DavidHammen we are supposed to be using imgur, not adding direct links for images, both for safety and to avoid link rot.