# Was Hagoromo's capture into lunar orbit ballistic capture or more propulsive?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbital-maneuver, hagoromo, hiten, ballistic-capture

Hagoromo was a ~36cm nano satellite that was deployed by [Hiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiten) while Hiten was in a highly elliptical orbit around the earth, in 1990.

From there, Hagoromo was able to [enter](http://thespacereview.com/article/3007/1) into an [orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17061/12102) around the [moon](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/muses-a_subsat.htm). Also see [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17296/12102) and any answers that may be there.

How was this done exactly? Was it purely ballistic capture (which still requires a tiny amount of thrust I think?) or more of a propulsive maneuver to enter into a lunar orbit?

What kind of propulsion and attitude control (if any) did Hagoromo actually have?

[image]

**above:** from [Gunter's Space Page](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/muses-a_subsat.htm)

[image]

**above:** from [Jaxa hitorical photos](http://www.isas.jaxa.jp/j/japan_s_history/picture/06.shtml) (found by googling "*はごろも JAXA*"). Hagoromo is the little one on the left, deployed for capture into lunar orbit from Hiten on the right as it passed near the moon in its highly elongated orbit around the earth - quite a cool robotic maneuver for a nano satellite in 1990 (and that's only the beginning of Hiten's story.)

[image]

**above:** from http://usi.kir.jp/CIA/ISAS/USI_cia_DS.html - models (presumably) of Hagoromo sitting on top of Hiten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive entry on Hagoromo](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1990-007B),

> A solid propellant (KM-L) retrorocket with a mass of 4 kg was mounted inside the spacecraft for orbit insertion.

Comment: With a nine pound firecracker like that, it must have had some kind of attitude control as well - be it passive or active. I wonder if it was somehow at least spin-stabilized?

Comment: I'll go look that up somehow. In the mean time, clearly it's the "or more propulsive" option.

Comment: I've just asked [How could tiny nanosatellite Hagoromo with a 4 kg solid propellant rocket inside maintain attitude control?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33392/12102)