# Have there been any spacecraft with internal SRM other than CONTOUR?

Tags: spacecraft, mission-design, solid-fuel

I read about the [CONTOUR mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONTOUR#Spacecraft) which used an internal solid rocket motor to change the trajectory. Have there been other spacecraft using a solid rocket motor which is not jettisoned after usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Muses A Lunar Orbiter (Hagoromo)]

**above:** from [Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/muses-a_subsat.htm)

---

According to Gunter's Space Page's [Muses A Lunar Orbiter (Hagoromo)](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/muses-a_subsat.htm):

> It was launched piggy-back on the Muses A (Hiten) probe into a highly elliptical Earth orbit which passed by the Moon ten times during the mission. At 19:37 UT on 18 March 1990 as Hiten approached its first lunar flyby, the small Hagoromo spacecraft was released into lunar orbit, making Japan the third nation to orbit the Moon. Although the S-band transmitter aboard Hagoromo had failed on 21 February 1990, the ignition of the Hagoromo deceleration rocket was confirmed by ground observation at 20:04:03 UT, the estimated orbit was 7400 × 20000 km with a period of 2.01 days. No contact could be established after orbit insertion.

@DavidHammen's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17299/12102) to the question "*Was Hagoromo's capture into lunar orbit ballistic capture or more propulsive?*":

> From the [NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive entry on Hagoromo](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1990-007B),
>
> > A solid propellant (KM-L) retrorocket with a mass of 4 kg was mounted inside the spacecraft for orbit insertion.

@DavidHammen's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17298/12102) to the question "*How could tiny Hagoromo have been seen visually from earth confirming its lunar orbit?*" is a click away and worth the read, so I won't re-quote it here.

See both (either) linked question for more images of this *kawaii* spacecraft and it's "parent" craft.

Comment: @thefall_ thanks for the accept, but if you leave the question open for a few more days it's possible more people will post answers. There may be more, and some of them even more interesting!

Answer (score 10):

The Soyuz descent module has SRMs that are fired just before touchdown. Does that count?